# Issue with indicating start/end dates in a generated calendar

Tags: php, events, calendar

I have an events calender which if theres an events it echos a color if blue on the day. I would like to display the start and end dates on the calender in the same way. Example if and events starts 01/01/2012 and ends 03/01/2012.

I'm having problems echoing a blue color from 01/01/2012 to 03/01/2012 to indicate the start and end date of the event.

The code belows show how I tried to solve the problem, it works but it thinks the event start from the 1st and end on the 3rd of every month which is wrong.

Please show me how I can improve this code or do different to make it work.
Thanks

```
  $todaysDate = date("d/m/Y");
  $dateToCompare = $daystring . '/' . $monthstring . '/' . $year;
  echo "<td align='center' ";

  if($todaysDate == $dateToCompare){
    echo "style='class:red'";
  }else{
    $sqlcount = mysql_query("select * from event where '".$dateToCompare."' >=start_date and '".$dateToCompare."' <=end_date");
    $customerCount = mysql_num_rows($sqlcount); // count the output amount

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlcount)) { 
      $start_date = $row['start_date'];
      $end_day = $row['end_day'];

      if($customerCount >= 1) echo "style='class:blue'";
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you just get start and end date from db.

```
$stmt = mysql_query(SELECT start_date, end_date FROM EVENT WHERE $your_key);
$event = fetch_array($stmt);
```

Get date between end and start, use a loop to color them like you want.